# Video doesn't fully clipped in circle path Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video, paint, clip-path

I want to clip a video widget inside a circle path with `CustomClipper<Path>`.

**Here is the empty circle clip :**

[image]

---

**And here is the video wrapped by the clipper**

[image]

The video is not fully clipped inside the circle and somehow drawn above the painter. This is happening while playing and not playing, and **according my tests only on IOS**

I'm using the better player to display video : https://pub.dev/packages/better_player .

I opened an issue on this lib because I suppose this could be a video problem. I'm facing this issue only with video in my app.

Here is the issue and the full code sample to run :   https://github.com/jhomlala/betterplayer/issues/696

Does anyone ever seen this behavior even with another case and know how to solve this ?

Comment: Try to change your radius to a very big number, say, 10000. Then see whether it is solved.

Comment: @ch271828n Sorry what's the point to do this ? the circle is drawn beyond the screen with this radius we can't see it , and then the video is on full screen

Comment: Ok then what about slighly make this number bigger, and then smaller, and then look at the screen to see whether the UI is changing.

Comment: Just tried. unfortunately the radius doesn't change anything, the video is not clipped.  I'm facing this issue only on IOS, there is no problem on Android. The owner of better player lib told in my GitHub issue that it could be a flutter issue on IOS according the platform view